# Какие есть хорошие видеокурсы по изучению ЯП Python?

Tags: python

Прошел несколько курсов по изучению базовых основ языка Python, а также курс по созданию GUI-приложений по библиотеке tkinter. После создал пару программ, которые значительно облегчили работу мне и моим коллегами. Но сейчас встал вопрос - что делать дальше?
Какие есть хорошие видеокурсы по дальнейшему изучению языка для людей с базовыми знаниями? Интересует несколько направлений - разработки мобильных приложений, GUI-приложений и WEB..

Answer (score 1):

После изучения основ не видеокурсах (эффективность такого подхода сомнительна, но тем не менее) не новые очередные "продвинутые" курсы надо искать, а реальные проекты. И  параллельно расширять свои знания по мере необходимости читая книги и документацию.  Реальные, а не поверхностные знания нарабатываются только при реальной работе, а еще лучше - под угрозой неполучения вознаграждения за проделанную роботу. Вот тогда и не будете на ерунду свое время и силы тратить, и запоминается все намного лучше. И никакие видеокурсы не дадут вам таких знаний и опыта.
А так - курсы для начинающих, курсы для "продолжающий", курсы для "продвинутых", потом что - курсы для "сеньоров"?

Comment: _потом что - курсы для "сеньоров"?_ - для "заканчивающих"